# Check fail and success in ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written an ajax post request to my login.php file, which echo's things such as "Incorrect" or "Success".

I'm not too sure how to use this function, as i also want to check for fails and stuff, and then add text to an error box for that..

Any idea?

Here is my current code:

```
$('#submit').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#loginForm').serialize(),
        beforeSend:function(){
            launchPreloader();
        },
        complete:function(){
            stopPreloader();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.href("chat.php");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're not sure how the ajax function works, start by reading the documentation and looking at the examples: api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You have a major flaw! There really is no need to use ajax if all you intend to do when the call completes is redirect to another page, basic HTML forms will do that by default.

Comment: @adeneo That would imply the OP wants to allow a form to be submitted (and have a page reload). The OP seems to want to implement an AJAX login, where the user is only redirected if the login is successful. That's quite a bit different from a simple HTML form

Comment: What is that `window.href` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery $.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).
>   These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when
>   the $.ajax() request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple
>   callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the
>   request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the
>   callback is fired immediately.) Available Promise methods of the jqXHR
>   object include:
>
> **jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {});** An alternative
>   construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces
>   the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for
>   implementation details.
>
> **jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});** An
>   alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method
>   replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for
>   implementation details.

Using your code as an example.....

```
$('#submit').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#loginForm').serialize(),
        beforeSend:function(){
            launchPreloader();
        },
        complete:function(){
            stopPreloader();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.href("chat.php");
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert('Done!');
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Fail!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Since `.done()` is an alternative to the success callback, there's no reason to use both. It's good practice to use *either* callback functions *or* promise methods, but not both. (They won't interfere with each other, but it can confuse future developers.)

Answer (score 1):

When you say detect fails I assume you mean bad requests etc... you can use the statusCode event to detect thinks like 404 errors and 500 internal servers errors like this:

```
statusCode: {
    404: function () {
        //console.log('Error: 404: Could not contact server.');
    },
    500: function () {
        //console.log('Error: 500: Server error occurred.');
    }
}
```

so the full ajax code would look like:

```
$('#submit').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#loginForm').serialize(),
        statusCode: {
           404: function () {
               //do somethign with error 404
               alert('Error: 404: Could not contact server.');
           },
           500: function () {
               //do something with error 500
               alert('Error: 500: Server error occurred.');
           }
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            launchPreloader();
        },
        complete:function(){
            stopPreloader();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.href("chat.php");
        }
    });
});
```

The Jquery ajax page gives a description of the 'statuscode' property http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

You could use this :

```
$('#submit').click( function() {
    launchPreloader();
    $.post({
        url: 'login.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#loginForm').serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
        // If the post request was successful
        stopPreloader();
        window.href("chat.php");
    }).fail(function(error) {
        // If there was an error with this request
        stopPreloader();
    });
});
```